# How to return Distinct Row using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have two rows which have all the data same except one column.
I want to show only one row on the UI but one row which has different data should be shown as comma seperated values.

Sample Data

```
PricingID  Name Age Group
1           abc 56  P1
1           abc 56  P2 

Output should be :
PricingID  Name Age Group
1           abc 56  P1,P2
```

I am using this approach but it is not working , it gives me two rows only but data i am able to concatenate with comma.

```
  List<PricingDetailExtended> pricingDetailExtendeds = _storedProcedures.GetPricingAssignment(pricingScenarioName, regionCode, productCode, stateCode, UserId, PricingId).ToList();
            var pricngtemp = pricingDetailExtendeds.Select(e => new
            {
                PricingID = e.PricingID,
                OpportunityID = e.OpportunityID,
                ProductName = e.ProductName,
                ProductCD = e.ProductCD
            });

            pricingDetailExtendeds.ForEach(e=>
                {
                    e.ProductCD =  string.Join(",",string.Join(",", (pricngtemp.ToList().Where(p => p.PricingID == e.PricingID).Select(k => k.ProductCD).ToArray())).Split(',').Distinct().ToArray());
                    e.OpportunityID =string.Join(",", string.Join(",", (pricngtemp.ToList().Where(p => p.PricingID == e.PricingID).Select(k => k.OpportunityID).ToArray())).Split(',').Distinct().ToArray());
                    e.ProductName =string.Join(",", string.Join(",", (pricngtemp.ToList().Where(p => p.PricingID == e.PricingID).Select(k => k.ProductName).ToArray())).Split(',').Distinct().ToArray());            


                }
                );

          //  pricingDetailExtendeds = GetUniquePricingList(pricingDetailExtendeds);

            return pricingDetailExtendeds.Distinct().AsEnumerable();
```

Any body can suggest me better approach and how to fix this issue ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where does name and age come into the code? Conversely, where does OpportunityID come into the table?

Comment: From Salesforce it comes into our DB one Pricing Id can have multiple oppurtunitiyId and if there are multiple oppurtunityid for one pricingid i should show as one row

Comment: Where's name and age then?

Comment: It is just a sample data

Comment: How does the same data relate to the code?

Comment: If you are open to non-LINQ solutions, I think you will see better average case performance with what you are trying to do.

Comment: i am open with non -LINQ option, tell me what's that ?

Comment: One example is that you could use the same idea behind `GroupBy` and create a `Dictionary` of the non-unique elements as the key. The difference is you know exactly what you intend to do with that data, so as the value of the hashtable, you could store whatever you want, such as a `StringBuilder`.
It shouldn't be that much more work to do.

Comment: I posted an example of to what I was referring. I've tested it and it seems to provide the functionality that you asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `GroupBy` linq function.

I then use the `String.Join` function to make the groups comma seperated.

So something like this:

```
var pricingDetailExtendeds = new[]
        {
            new
            {
                PricingID = 1,
                Name = "abc",
                Age = 56,
                Group = "P1"
            },
            new
            {
                PricingID = 1,
                Name = "abc",
                Age = 56,
                Group = "P2"

            }
        };
        var pricngtemp =
            pricingDetailExtendeds.GroupBy(pde => new {pde.PricingID, pde.Name, pde.Age})
                .Select(g => new {g.Key, TheGroups = String.Join(",", g.Select(s => s.Group))}).ToList();
```

You can easily extrapolate this to the other fields.

To return the `PricingDetailExtended`, the just create it in the select. So something like this

```
.Select(g => new PricingDetailExtended { 
    PricingID = g.Key.PricingId, 
    TheGroups = String.Join(",", g.Select(s => s.Group))
}).ToList();
```

You won't have the field `TheGroups` though, so just replace that field with the proper one.

Comment: var pricngtemp = pricingDetailExtendeds.GroupBy(e => new
            {
                PricingID = e.PricingID,
                OpportunityID = e.OpportunityID,
                ProductName = e.ProductName,
                ProductCD = e.ProductCD
            }).Select(g => new { g.Key, TheGroups = String.Join(",", g.Select(s => s.ProductCD)) }).ToList(); 
            return pricingDetailExtendeds.Distinct().AsEnumerable();

Comment: Two things, 1) you have included the `ProductCD` in your group, you want to create a group of products based on some criteria, so don't include the products 2) You don't need the `Distinct()`

Comment: Can you pls modify the above code and tell me i have removed Distinct() and in my case Group = ProductCD but it does not work

Comment: Also remove ProductName from the group

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83897/discussion-between-nathan-koop-and-user662285).

Comment: Your comment is good, the problem was with Oppurtunityid as it was diffrent for both the rows i have removed the same now i am getting 1 row..now the problem is how to return this single row as my method expects IEnumerable<PricingDetailExtended> as return type  but i am geeting the data in var variable which is anonymoust type ??

Comment: @user662285 see latest revision.

Comment: Now your code return correct ProductName , how to return other fields ??

Comment: use the same technique, instead of `TheGroups = ... .Select(s => s.Group)` do `TheOtherGroup = ... .Select( s=> s.ProductName)` etc...

Comment: i am using like this :   RegionCD = g.Select(s => s.RegionCD) but it gives error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to string'

Comment: @user662285 use `String.Join`

Answer (score 1):

An example of what I was describing in my comment would be something along the lines of the following. I would expect this to be moved into a helper function.

```
List<PriceDetail> list = new List<PriceDetail>
{
    new PriceDetail {Id = 1, Age = 56, Name = "abc", group = "P1"},
    new PriceDetail {Id = 1, Age = 56, Name = "abc", group = "P2"},
    new PriceDetail {Id = 2, Age = 56, Name = "abc", group = "P1"}
};

Dictionary<PriceDetailKey, StringBuilder> group = new Dictionary<PriceDetailKey, StringBuilder>();

for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; ++i)
{
    var key = new PriceDetailKey { Id = list[i].Id, Age = list[i].Age, Name = list[i].Name };               
    if (group.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        group[key].Append(",");
        group[key].Append(list[i].group);
    }
    else
    {
        group[key] = new StringBuilder();
        group[key].Append(list[i].group);
    }
}

List<PriceDetail> retList = new List<PriceDetail>();
foreach (KeyValuePair<PriceDetailKey, StringBuilder> kvp in group)
{
    retList.Add(new PriceDetail{Age = kvp.Key.Age, Id = kvp.Key.Id, Name = kvp.Key.Name, group = kvp.Value.ToString()});
}
```

you could even convert the final loop into a LINQ expression like:

```
group.Select(kvp => new PriceDetail {Age = kvp.Key.Age, Id = kvp.Key.Id, Name = kvp.Key.Name, group = kvp.Value.ToString()});
```

Its worth noting you could do something similar without the overhead of constructing new objects if, for example, you wrote a custom equality comparer and used a list instead of dictionary. The upside of that is that when you were finished, it would be your return value without having to do another iteration.

There are several different ways to get the results. You could even do the grouping in SQL.

Comment: Where you are making 2 rows into one ? see the sample data above ..how the output should be ?

Comment: I'm doing it in the first for loop. Run the example, it does what you want.
I'm using a `Dictionary` to check for duplicates. When I find a duplicate, I append the only relevant data to the `StringBuilder` and never add the new row to the `Dictionary`.
Then the `Dictionary` will contain distinct rows with the relevant data from the eliminated rows.